# How to create a dynamic label for a form field in Odoo 12?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-12

I have a form view. I added to it the field `main_field`, but I want to change its label dynamically, depending on the value of other field named `conditional_field`. This is my main attempt:

```
<group>
    <group name="xxx">
        <field name="conditional_field" invisible="1"/>
        <label for="main_field" string="AAA" attrs="{'invisible': [('conditional_field', '!=', 'A')]}"/>
        <label for="main_field" string="BBB" attrs="{'invisible': [('conditional_field', '!=', 'B')]}"/>
        <div>
            <field name="main_field" class="oe_inline"/>
        </div>
    </group>
</group>
```

The problem of this solution is that the labels are always there, just invisible, but actually they are taking space.

If *BBB* is hidden, `main_field` appears under the label *AAA*, because *BBB* is invisible but taking place at the right of *AAA*.
If *AAA* is hidden, `main_field` appears under the label *BBB*, and *BBB* is at the right side, because at the left side is the invisible *AAA* taking place, so it looks even uglier.

The problem is that Odoo is setting `display: none;` to labels, but is preserving the style of the cell they are in, so my method does not work properly.

Any ideas? I am trying to avoid create auxiliary fields for each label because I have to do this with a lot of labels and that would be a mess. Thank you!

Comment: can you inspect that element with check css and remove the extra padding if it is there.later you can use scss in you module.

Comment: @DipenShah That could be a solution but I was looking for one using Odoo framework. I am going to post a solution I made, take a look and give your opinion if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of attempts, I found a solution. It is not perfect, due to the cell separator: the border disappears, so I had to replicate it with CSS, and it is not as higher as the original one. But it does not look very bad, enough for my situation.

```
<group>
    <group name="xxx">
        <field name="conditional_field" invisible="1"/>
            <div class="o_form_label" style="border-right:0.8px solid #ddd; width:101%;">
                <label for="main_field" string="AAA" attrs="{'invisible': [('conditional_field', '!=', 'A')]}" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
                <label for="main_field" string="BBB" attrs="{'invisible': [('conditional_field', '!=', 'B')]}" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
            </div>
            <field name="main_field" nolabel="1" style="padding-left:8px;"/>
        </field>
    </group>
</group>
```

Obviously, **the CSS styles will change depending on which part of the form you    are placing the label in**. For example, if you want to do this in the classic totals section of invoices, orders, etc. this will be the code:

```
<group class="oe_subtotal_footer oe_right">
    <field name="conditional_field" invisible="1"/>
    <div class="oe_right">
        <label for="main_field" string="AAA" attrs="{'invisible': [('conditional_field', '!=', 'A')]}" style="font-weight:bold; margin:0;"/>
        <label for="main_field" string="BBB" attrs="{'invisible': [('conditional_field', '!=', 'B')]}" style="font-weight:bold; margin:0;"/>
    </div>
    <field name="main_field" nolabel="1"/>
</group>
```

Anyway, if someone finds a better solution, I will change the accepted answer and give it to them.

**EDIT**

For newer versions, this is an easier solution:

```
<div class="o_td_label">
    <label for="main_field" string="AAA" attrs="{'invisible': [('conditional_field', '!=', 'A')]}"/>
    <label for="main_field" string="BBB" attrs="{'invisible': [('conditional_field', '!=', 'B')]}"/>
</div>
<field name="main_field" nolabel="1"/>
```